# ModSecurity Command Injection not working

Tags: windows, injection, mod-security

I am testing web application firewall and I have installed ModSecurity 2.9  runs Core ModSecurity Rule Set ver.2.2.9   and to test on Web application I also install DVWA  Platform: Windows
and trying to do Command Inject and it allows even if  I included rules for command inject
modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf
all other rules for SQLinject,XSS etc  works fine .
[image: Command Injection in windows]

the Rule for Command Inject is as follows

`` SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "@rx (?i)(?:;|\{|\||\|\||&|&&|\n|\r|`)\s*[\(,@\'\"\s]*(?:[\w'\"\./]+/|[\\\\'\"\^]*\w[\\\\'\"\^]*:.*\\\\|[\^\.\w '\"/\\\\]*\\\\)?[\"\^]*(?:\.[\"\^]*\w+)?\b" \
        "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'8',capture,t:none,t:normalisePath,ctl:auditLogParts=+E,block,msg:'System Command Injection',id:'950907',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-31',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1',tag:'PCI/6.5.2',logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0},skipAfter:END_COMMAND_INJECTION1"

SecMarker END_COMMAND_INJECTION1 ``


I want to know what can be done so that if I inject a command  127.0.0.1 & shutdown /l or anything after "&" in textbox  the ModSecurity must redirect to 403 error page . 
I have read similar post and solutions if I try my apache server will crash .

Answer (score 0):

Your rule set (2.2.9) is "bit" old, you should use a newer version (actually 3.3).

I don't understand your question exactly "*what can be done if I inject...*".

As you can see, the operator is the `@rx`, and it has an argument. The list of variables contains the `ARGS`, so I guess your form contains an input field, what will evaluated as an argument (member of `ARGS`). [Here](https://regex101.com/r/6jbNJT/1) I tried to demonstrate how this rule checks your request.

If your rule doesn't triggered, then it means the comparison (your input field with the operator argument) doesn't match, or the engine isn't turned on.

So, please check your `SecRuleEngine` setting, it must be on `On`.

My 2 cents: may be the rule misses the `t:urlDecode` transformation, because if you sent the character `&`, I assume your browser will send it as encoded form.

Answer (score 0):

If possible update your Modsecurity as @airween said.

If I understand correctly you want blocking directly when detecting such an attack, if this is it:

- Change the disruptive action of the rule from "block" to "deny"

View details: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#deny